# Usar a formula "se" para calcular um determinado intervalo de tempo

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou tentando criar uma condição  mas estou tendo dificuldade,  alguem pode me ajudar?

se o numero da celula c15   estiver entre -00:10 e 0:10 (minutos) a celula d15 deverá aparecer 0:00, caso contrario a celula d15 deve mostrar o mesmo numero da celula c15.  Como mnetar essa condição.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Olá, ja conseguiu resover o problema de não ser possivel colocar diretamente as horas negativamente ?

Comment: Ricardo, bem vindo ao Soft. Acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour, para usar melhor os recursos daqui e ver como tratar as perguntas e respostas. Procure ser claro es suas questões e colocar parte do já fez, código, fórmulas ou parte da planilha (dá para inserir imagem).

Comment: Olá Ricardo, aqui tem alguns modelos que possuem algo parecido, caso ajude em algo. https://github.com/excelguru/controle-de-ponto Abs

Comment: Oi @Ricardo, a resposta que dei te serviu de alguma forma? Se sim, por favor, marque a resposta no "check" abaixo da pontuação de votação da resposta. Grato.

Answer (score 4):

O **Excel** não trabalha (faz operações) com horas negativas, provavelmente você está tratando a hora como uma "string" (formato texto, p.ex.: ="00:05").

Neste caso, mesmo para uma "string", o **Excel** entende que é horas se estivar positivo, seja no formato padrão **"00:00:00"** ou em outro, caso sua lista de formatos para hora contemple **"00:00"**.

Então, como entre **"00:10"** minutos e **"-00:10"** minutos, os valores estão entre 0 e 10 em "valores absolutos", faça o seguinte:

1. Retire o sinal negativo da hora para fazer a comparação
2. Em outra célula, pegue o "Valor" desta hora, assim:

   =Valor(A1)
3. O resultado será um número que representa esta hora para o **Excel**. Como **"00:10"** minutos é igual a **0,000115740740740741**, se a célula estiver entre este valor e 0, a hora está no intervalo que deseja.

Fiz o teste usando a hora assim:

> **="00:00:09"**
>
> **="00:00:10"**
>
> **="00:00:11"**

E a fórmula:

```
=Se(Valor(C15)<0,000115740740740741;"00:00:00";C15)
```

ou melhor...

```
=Se(Valor(C15)<Valor("00:00:10");"00:00:00";C15)
```

É só adaptar para o teu caso e aplicar!