# Usar a função SE do Excel para calcular a diferença entre horas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Bom dia.

Tenho uma planilha de calculo de horas trabalhadas e quero acrescentar uma coluna onde vou calcular a quanto tempo de adicional noturno eu faço, porém nem sempre faço esse horário a mais.
Para isso preciso calcular da seguinte forma( irei usar nome das células fictícias para exemplificar):

- Valores das células:
  C02 = 22:30:00
- Condição que quero criar uma formula usando SE:
  SE C02 > 22:00  então E02= C02-22:00  senão E02= 0

obs: tentei usar escrevendo algo parecido no Excel, porém dava erro, tinha escrito da seguinte forma:

SE(C02> 22:00:00; C02-22:00:00; 00:00:00)

Espero que possam me ajudar.

Obrigado

Comment: isso ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142891/usar-a-formula-se-para-calcular-um-determinado-intervalo-de-tempo

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que dessa forma te ajude:

```
=SE(C8>C9;C8-C9;0)
```

Onde:

**C8** é a hora de saída

**C9** é a hora limite para contabilizar a hora extra

O erro pode acontecer por conta da forma na qual você insere os dados na fórmula, tente seguir esse exemplo no preenchimento com dados brutos ao invés de referenciar na célula:

```
=SE(C8>"22:00:00";C8-"22:00:00";0)
```